# What is "draftId" in Banno Segments API

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

In this page https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/api-reference/v0/segments/details/
we have an API to create a Segment.

Endpoint - /a/segments/api/v0/institutions/{institutionId}/segments

Example Payload

{
"name": "string",
"sourceProvider": "string",
"draftId": "string"
}

**What is draftId ? Where do we get this value from (or) is this a random UUID that gets passed ot the Segment creation API**

I am looking for an explanation for the request Body parameters in Segment creation API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `draftId` is unique id of the draft to be used to create the segment. It is a UUID that you will pass in the POST request.